# can't make EF work with my existing DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this 4 tables on my database, i am trying to retrieve which fleets are assigned to a user which session is open and also the selected fleet.

```
dbo.UserAccount 
UserID       (PK,uniqueidentifier,not null)
PrimaryFleet (FK,uniqueidentifier,not null) 
SelectedFleet(FK,uniqueidentifier,not null)
```

the UserAccount table has 2 FK, which both point to the column dbo.Fleets.OwnerID

```
dbo.Session
SessionID (PK,uniqueidentifier,not null)
UserID    (FK,uniqueidentifier,not null)
```

the Session table has a FK pointing to dbo.UserAccount.UserID

```
dbo.UserFleet
UserID    (FK,uniqueidentifier,not null)
OwnerID   (FK,uniqueidentifier,not null)
```

UserFleet is just a table to know which fleets are assigned to each user, so its a many to many relation

```
dbo.Fleets
OwnerId (PK,uniqueidentifier,not null)
ownerName (nvarchar(255),not null)
```

I am trying with the following code. which works correctly except that my var fleets returns empty, i don't know how to tell entity framework how to relate dbo.UserAccount with dbo.Fleets via the table UserFleet.

```
if (HttpContext.Session["Session"] == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                var response = new getchangesModel();
                var session = new Guid(HttpContext.Session["Session"].ToString());
                using(Dal.DbContext dc = new Dal.DbContext())
                {
                    var SessionSet = dc.Sessions.Where(S => S.SessionID == session).Include(d => d.UserAccount).SingleOrDefault();
                    var SelectedFleet = dc.Fleets.Where(f => f.OwnerId == SessionSet.UserAccount.SelectedFleet).SingleOrDefault(); 
                    var fleets = dc.UserAccounts.Where(u => u.UserID == SessionSet.UserAccount.UserID).Include(f => f.Fleet);  
                }
```

This is my models definition

```
[Table("Session")]
public class Session
{
    [Key]
    public Guid SessionID { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }
}
[Table("Fleets")]
public class Fleet
{
    [Key]
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public String ownerName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccount { get; set; }     

}
 [Table("UserAccount")]
 public class UserAccount
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name="UserID")] 
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }         
    public Guid SelectedFleet {   get; set; }
    public Guid? PrimaryFleet { get; set; }
    public virtual Fleet Fleet { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Session> Session { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EF does not know what column PrimaryFleet or SecondaryFleet is related to your property Feet. You can specify this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
    .HasRequired(a => a.Fleet)
    .WithMany(a => a.UserAccount)
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.SelectedFleet);
```

or

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
    .HasOptional(a => a.Fleet)
    .WithMany(a => a.UserAccount)
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.PrimaryFleet);
```

Previous answer.

According your database design, tables UserAccount and Fleets have many-to-many relationship (via UserFleet table). But your classes design means that UserAccount can have only one Fleet. So, at first replace

```
public virtual Fleet Fleet { get; set; }
```

to

```
public virtual ICollection<Fleet> Fleets { get; set; }
```

and at second add the following code to OnModelCreating method of your DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
        .HasMany<Fleet>(s => s.Fleets)
        .WithMany(c => c.UserAccounts) // i renamed your Fleet.UserAccount property to UserAccounts to show that it is collection
        .Map(cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("UserID");
                cs.MapRightKey("OwnerID");
                cs.ToTable("UserFleet");
            });

}
```

Comment: But how do i tell it to map the guids useraccount.selectedfleet and useraccount.primary fleet to fleet?

Comment: Sorry, but i do not understand what are relationships between useraccount and fleet. Table UserFleet means many-to-many, but class design means one-to-many. What is the relationship?

Comment: Well, I would recommend to use field name pattern <Something>ID for key columns (PK and FK), usage of EF default naming convension can help you to get gid of a lot of mappings. For instance, if column has name PrimaryFleetID then you can define corresponding properties public Guid PrimaryFleetID {get;set;} and public Fleet PrimaryFleet {get;set;} and EF automaps them

Comment: in previous comment phrase "can help you to get gid of a lot of mappings" should be read as "can help you to get rid of a lot of mappings"

Comment: I don't get it, in your answer you state that i have to get one or the other, but what if i need to get both? one userAccount has a selectedfleet and a primaryfleet

Comment: Let's add two properties to your class: public virtual Fleet PrimaryFleetEntity { get; set; } and public virtual Fleet SelectedFleetEntity { get; set; } and apply mapping from my answer for both of them

Comment: I think i know where you are heading and it seems right, just that i can't make the mapping, i get an error `cannot implicitly convert type Fleet to IColecctionFleet>` my mapping is like this `modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
                .HasMany<Fleet>(c => c.PrimaryFleetEntity)
                .WithMany(i => i.UserAccount)
                .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("SelectedFleet")
                    .MapRightKey("OwnerId")
                    .ToTable("Fleets"));`

Comment: it happens because you try to map PrimaryFleetEntity with HasMany(). UserAccount does not has many PrimaryFleetEntity, it has only one PrimaryFleetEntity and one SelectedFleetEntity. Try two mappings from beginning of my answer. Sorry, but i still do not undestand how many relations between UserAccount and Fleet. According your tables there are three relationships: two of them (UserAccount.PrimaryFleet and UserAccount.SelectedFleet) are one-to-many and the last is many-to-many via UserFleet. You try to mix these relationships and as result you have problems with mapping.

Comment: Does UserAccount HAS Fleet collection (more that 2 items) and one item can be Primary and another one can be Selected?

Comment: Im sorry if a confused you, i have 3 relations, 2 of them are one-one, which are the primary and selected ones, and the third onw is a many to many, with the table dbo.UserFleet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139184/discussion-between-pato-llaguno-and-alex-zemtsov).